# XSLT syntax in schematron to lookup attribute in another xml document and return another attribute from the same entry

Tags: xml, xslt, schematron

**[Updated]**
See my comment below - I'm having difficulty connecting to/pull in the reference document data (file name is problems.xml).

Here is a link to a sample source xml document (to run the xsl against):
https://github.com/chb/sample_ccdas/blob/master/Cerner%20Samples/problems-and-medications.xml

This is a small sample from problems.xml I need to cross-reference, matching data from the sample above (`cda:ClinicalDocument/cda:component/cda:structuredBody/cda:component/cda:section/cda:entry/cda:act/cda:entryRelationship/cda:observation/cda:value/@displayName`) to the `code/value` here, and comparing the displayName = displayName:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<systems xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.lantanagroup.com/voc">
    <system valueSetOid="2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.12.3221.7.4" valueSetName="Problem">
     <code value="10000006" displayName="Radiating chest pain (finding)" codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" />
     <code value="10001005" displayName="Bacterial sepsis (disorder)" codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" />
     <code value="10007009" displayName="Coffin-Siris syndrome (disorder)" codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" />
     <code value="1001000119102" displayName="Pulmonary embolism with pulmonary infarction (disorder)" codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" />
     <code value="1001000124104" displayName="Normal left ventricular systolic function (finding)" codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" />
     <code value="10017004" displayName="Occlusal wear of teeth (disorder)" codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" />
     <code value="100191000119105" displayName="Asymmetry of prostate (finding)" codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" />
    </system>
</systems>
```

Here is the entire (incorrect) syntax in my now xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" >

    <xsl:variable name="SNOMEDCTProblems" select="document('voc.xml')/systems/system[@valueSetOid='2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.12.3221.7.4']"/>
    <xsl:key match="$SNOMEDCTProblems/code[@value]" name="problemsKey" use="@value"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <u>
                    <b>
                        <h4>Name does not match Canonical name</h4>
                    </b>
                </u>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>displayName</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each default-collation="key('problemsKey', @value, @displayName)/@displayName = 
                                                             $problemEntries/cda:entry/cda:act/cda:entryRelationship/cda:observation/cda:value/@displayName">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="cda:entryRelationship/cda:observation/cda:value/@displayName" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Original]
I have a schematron file for doing validation of xml files for content. Some of the content I need to validate against already exists in a separate xml file. Essentially, I need to look in the xml i'm validating, find the value (code) for an entry and its corresponding name (displayName), look the value up in the reference file (value), fetch its corresponding name (displayName), then compare the two names and verify they are the same (displayName = displayName).

This is what the entry in the xml file I'm validating looks like:

```
<value xsi:type="OK" code="12345" displayName="Rounds"
```

This is what the separate xml file data looks like, to validate against:

```
<system valueSet="999999999" valueSetName="Widgets">
    <code value="12345" displayName="Round" />
    <code value="246810" displayName="Square" />
    <code value="13579" displayName="Triangular" />
```

I've already been able to find the syntax for referencing the file and a specific field in the file. Getting to the 'code' would be something like:

```
document('<name-here>.xml')/<xpath-here>[@valueSet='999999999']/code/@value
```

However, i'm not sure how to return the value another attribute in the same entry to then compare with. Any suggestions or guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 2  based implementation of Schematron? Does Schematron allow you to declare XSLT keys for cross reference lookup? In XSLT 2 you could use e.g. `<xsl:key name="code-ref" match="system[@valueSet]/code[@value]" use="@value"/>` and then compare e.g. `key('code-ref', @code, doc('codes.xml')//system[@valueSet = '999999999'])/@displayName = @displayName`.

Comment: The xsl:key approach noted by Martin is the most efficient approach. The plain xPath approach would be something like this:

`<sch:rule context="value">
<sch:assert test="@displayName = document('<name-here>.xml')/<xpath-here>[@valueSet='999999999']/code[@value = current()/@code]/@displayName">...</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>`

Comment: Thanks for both comments. I was pulled away from this for a while and in recent days have been trying to apply the above. One change is I aborted the schematron route and decided to go with XSLT. However, I can't get to the step of working out the syntax. Every time I try and reference the document I get "No recognized collation URI found in default-collation attribute..." Haven't figured out how to pull in the data. I'm updating the original post with my currently not working xsl file contents and a link to an example.